# Highcharts - append % to first axis label?

Tags: highcharts

When styling a chart axis, a common style in publications is to include the unit or percentage sign only on the topmost label of the Y-axis. I am trying to figure out how to do this in Highcharts.

I know I can hard-code a number, like this:

```
 yAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            if ( this.value == 12 ) {
               return this.value + "%";
            } else {
               return this.value;
            }
        }
    },
```

But this is not a very flexible solution.

Is there a way to test for the first (or nth) value displayed? Is there a way to get the index of a value within the formatter function?

### 2013 Update

This works in most circumstances:

```
if ( this.value == this.axis.getExtremes().max )
    return this.value + '%';
else 
    return this.value;
```

However, it does *not* work if you have `yAxis.endOnTick` set to false—because in that case the maximum **value** of the axis is not the same as the highest **label** on the axis.

Is there a way to get that highest ***label*** from within the formatter function?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, it isn't possible to find the 'nth' item on an axis, but first and last can be dome using the properties `this.isFirst` and `this.isLast' in stead of checking`this.value`

If you want to, you can also access the axis itself directly using `this.axis`, so you should be able to run whatever complex logic you want on the axis itself..

Comment: Thanks! This got me on the right track. I ended up using a solution with `this.axis.getExtremes().max`, which I may post separately.

Comment: See 2013 update—this doesn't work when `endOnTick` is false. So I'm still looking for a magic solution.

Answer (score 2):

With 4.2.x version of highchart I have achieved it with following code

```
labels: {
    formatter: function () {
        if(this.isFirst)
            return this.value + "%";
        else
            return this.value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also add `[%]` to the name of the yAxis. Then you wouldn't have to tamper with the ticks.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw at max value `plotLine` and after extremes are changed - remove and add new one). Then label for that plotLine you can set as '%' and move to the left side.

Another solution is to use axis title - set it to top and remove rotation.

The last solutions (or rather workaround) is to use second yAxis, and set there min and max(or tickPositions), and show only last label, and first hide.

Comment: Paweł, would any of the Highcharts updates of the last few years make this possible? To recap, I'm trying to access the first label on an axis from within the formatter function—specifically when the axis doesn't end on a label (i.e. `endOnTick` is `false`), so I can't simply compare the label value to the max of the axis.

Comment: Now, when I think about it, how about using `this.isFirst` flag? See [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter).